# How to use PEM certeficate to update my react native application

Tags: android, google-play, pem

I asked google play console support to update my keys to publish my current react native android APP because i lost my old key.
They asked me for a pem certificate that i generated in my local machine and sent it and they told my the the new keys are generated but i don't know how to use my PEM certeficate to sign again my APP

Can any one explain to me how does it work?   . THANKS